# specifying characters that cannot be typed

Tags: jquery, keycode

what i want to do is ensure that " ' are characters that do not get typed into the input box  I have a variety of key-press codes that restrict users to a-z and 0-9 but some how i cannot seem to make it work in a manner that i can restrict to not typing a few characters rather than specifying what needs to be typed.

http://jsfiddle.net/cG4aV/ - tryign to restrict enter key (works) , "  '  (does not work)

it also does not work for any key that activates with a shift...

any ideas

Comment: It's working for `enter, " and '` for me :s

Comment: @joy odd.. i am using firefox ...how about you

Comment: try this `var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);` to determine the code

Comment: Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/cG4aV/4/

Comment: @joy yes it works thanks but i can use which  instead of keycode ...as per mgi answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see it works on Chrome, but not on Firefox. Try replacing `keyCode` for `which`, it's normalized for all browsers.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/cG4aV/1/), should work in both browsers now.

Quoting jQuery docs on [event.which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/):

> The event.which property normalizes event.keyCode and event.charCode. It is recommended to watch event.which for keyboard key input. For more detail, read about event.charCode on the MDC.

So, it's enough to test for `which`, no need to check `keyCode` or `charCode`.

Comment: nope, tested here in IE6 (the only one I have) and it worked fine. Should work with newer versions too.

Comment: thanks if it works on ie6 it will work any where *cross fingers* :)

Answer (score 0):

The correct expression for determining the code cross-browser is

```
var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
```

And it's working for me in `firefox 12`

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/cG4aV/4/)

But you should better use `e.which` as per [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) says

> The event.which property normalizes event.keyCode and event.charCode.
>   It is recommended to watch event.which for keyboard key input.